# Ubpublish/ making private youtube video from youtube data api v3 using nodejs

Tags: node.js, youtube, youtube-data-api

Hello I upload a video on youtube using nodejs with scheduled date and time and it is uploaded correctly with the following code. I want to put some parameters here so that it can be unpublished or make it private at at some specific time. e.g in the example below if i upload the video so it will be public on 2017-12-28 16:10:00. Which works fine. But if i want to set this video to be automatically unpublished / private on 2018-01-28 16:10:00. How can i do this?

```
    const publishDate = new Date("2017-12-28 16:10:00");
var req = Youtube.videos.insert({
            resource: {
                snippet: {
                    title: "Dummy video to test scheduled time"
                  , description: "Dummy video to test scheduled time"
                }
              , status: {
                            privacyStatus: "private",
                    publishAt: publishDate //Scheduled
                }
            }
            // This is for the callback function
          , part: "snippet,status"
            // Create the readable stream to upload the video
          , media: {
                body: fs.createReadStream("video.mp4")
            }
        }, (err, data) => {
            console.log("Done.");
            process.exit();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

As i can see there is no such way to pass ubpublish date while upload. I have handled this using update video option.
Would be nice if someone comes with better solution.